# BLE connection in Unity

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to Unity and BLE, so I am having trouble getting Bluetooth connection. I tried following along the solution posted here: [BLE device with Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686302/ble-device-with-unity#comment107382716_60686302)

But, I can't work it out. I have added the WclGattClientDll to my assets folder, but can't figure out how to connect to my Bluetooth device. My Bluetooth device uses the heart rate service and works properly, since it connects to the manufacturers phone app.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Hello, We have just answered on your e-mail. Please check out links we sent in that email first. If that does not help please do not hesitate to contact us. The very first thing I recommend to take a look on is this article: https://www.btframework.com/ble.htm

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Currently your post contains no useful information whatsoever for us to help you with. Please explain what isn't working (are you getting any errors?) and the relevant code. Please read he [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on how to improve your post, and increase the chances of getting answers

Comment: This question lacks information. You say you followed the solution but can't get it to work, but you don't explain what exactly is not working. Are you getting errors? What debugging did you try? Did you manage to follow the solution properly or had any difficulties?

Answer (score 1):

This could be down to a permission problem. It is possible to solve this issue in both Unity (pre-build) and Visual Studio (post-build). Here are both solutions:

#### Solution A: in Unity

1. Head to **Edit > Project Settings > Player**.
2. In the **Inspector**, open up the tab **Publishing Settings**.
3. Under the **Capabilities** section, make sure that **Bluetooth is enabled**.

[image]
*Click on the .gif to expand*

#### Solution B: in Visual Studio (2017)

1. In your **Solution Explorer** (Ctrl+Alt+L), expand your project.
2. Double-click the **Package.appxmanifest**.
3. Go to the **Capabilities** tab.
4. Again, make sure that **Bluetooth is enabled**.

[image]
*Click on the .gif to expand*

This will give your app the right to use Bluetooth.

Comment: the option doesn't seem to appear here anymore for unity

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/adabru/BleWinrtDll

For my project I created a UWP-BLE wrapper as C++-dll that you can copy into Unity. It works for the Unity-Editor and the Windows standalone version. It has only the basic functions but you can extend it with the rest of the UWP-API if you are willing to write some C++.